# How to remove text between two strings, including identifiers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have a requirement to remove the text between two strings.
An example of the text is:

```
Abc%678x”cv ","@metadata":{abxkl "DataArray"}},{"columnName":"
```

The requirement is to start removing text from `,"@met` till `"}`

The requirement is to use `,"@met` and `"}` as start and end identifiers and remove text between them including the identifiers.

There could be multiple occurrence of this start and end identifiers within the file.

The output should look like this:

```
Abc%678x”cv "},{"columnName":"
```

How to write an Excel formula or simple VBA script to remove text between two strings, including identifiers?

Answer (score 2):

Formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",""@met",A1)-1)&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("}",A1,FIND("""@met",A1)))
```

VBA function:

```
Function RemoveBetweenSeparators( _
    ByVal MyString As String, _
    ByVal SepL As String, _
    ByVal SepR As String) _
    As String

    Dim sL As String
    Dim sR As String

    sL = Split(MyString, SepL)(0)
    sR = Replace(MyString, sL, "")
    sR = Replace(sR, Split(sR, SepR)(0) & SepR, "")

    RemoveBetweenSeparators = sL & sR
End Function
```

Which can be used like this:

```
=RemoveBetweenSeparators(A1,"""@meta","}")
```

EDIT: I also missed the 'multiple occurences' requirement, first time round! That makes it a little trickier, but try this:

```
Function RemoveBetweenSeparatorsMultiple( _
    ByVal MyString As String, _
    ByVal SepL As String, _
    ByVal SepR As String) _
    As String

    Dim sOut As String
    Dim sL As String

    Do Until InStr(MyString, SepL) = 0
        sL = Split(MyString, SepL)(0)
        sOut = sOut & sL
        MyString = Replace(MyString, sL & SepL, "", 1, 1)
        sL = Split(MyString, SepR)(0)
        MyString = Replace(MyString, sL & SepR, "", 1, 1)
    Loop

    RemoveBetweenSeparatorsMultiple = sOut & MyString

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, i am running few test cases, ll update shortly.

Comment: Hi Olly, I would like to pass input parameter value for SepL as ,"@meta could you let me know how to prefix comma (,) in the parameter value pls? =RemoveBetweenSeparators(A1,",""@meta","}") returns error.

Comment: That formula works for me, with the text string you posted in your question. See https://excel.solutions/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/so1711pk.xlsm for worked example.

Answer (score 1):

My apology, didn't notice that there could be multiple occurrence. I'll edit my answer later.

Assuming the original text is stored in A1.

`A2=LEFT(A1,FIND(",""@met",A1)-1)&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("""}",A1)-1)`

Note: If you need to force excel treat a double quote mark as a normal text, you have to type two `"` for representing a `"`.

If there may be multiple occurrence, try this

```
Private Function RemoveText(ByVal tgtString As String, ByVal StartText As String, ByVal EndText As String) As String
    Do While InStr(1, tgtString, StartText) > 0
        tgtString = Left(tgtString, InStr(1, tgtString, StartText) - 1) & Right(tgtString, Len(tgtString) - InStr(1, tgtString, EndText) - 1)
    Loop

    RemoveText = tgtString
End Function

Private Sub test()
    'remove certain string in A1 and store the result in A2
    Range("A2").Value = RemoveText(Range("A1").Value, ",""@met", """}")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, ll try and revert shortly.

Answer (score 0):

maybe somthing like this (not tested though!) :

```
    Function cleanedStr (inpStr as String; beginDel as string; endDel as Str) as String
    Dim idx     as long
    Dim take    as boolean
    Dim outStr  as String
    Dim myCh    as String

        take = true
        outStr = ""
        for idx = 1 to len(inpStr)
            myCh = mid(inpStr, idx, 1)
            if myCh = beginDel then take = false
            if take then 
                outStr = outStr & myCh
            else
                if myCh = endDel then take = true
            end if
        next idx        
        cleanedStr = outStr    
    end Function
```

Mind, the begin-identifier is 1 character only.
beginDel would be @ and endDel would be }

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily using VBA and regular expressions:

```
Option Explicit
Function RemoveBetweenDelimiters(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = ",""@met[^}]+}"
    RemoveBetweenDelimiters = .Replace(S, "")
End With

End Function
```

The regex interpretation:

### ,"@met[^}]+}

```
,"@met[^}]+}
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Match the character string “,"@met” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `,"@met`
- [Match any character that is NOT a “}”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[^}]+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the character “}” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `}`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)